# Проблема с margin

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap, веб-программирование

Верстаю макет, использую Bootstrap. Столкнулся с такой проблемой: `margin` по факту есть и влияет на расположение элементов, но во вкладке `computed` он не отображается, в CSS файлах тоже не могу его найти.
Соответственно, не знаю к какому классу или объекту дать нулевой `margin`.

[image: margin problem]  [image: margin problem again]

Столкнулся с такой проблемой уже не первый раз. Подскажите пожалуйста в каком направлении искать решение?

Comment: скорее всего, это не правый марджин, а флоат лефт. а оранжевым показывает оставшееся место. либо надо заходить глубже и смотреть отступы там - на внутренних элементах.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1)
Зачем вы для `li` указываете классы `col-*`?
Попробуйте так, `HTML`:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
  <li class="service">
    <div class="panel panel-default>
  </li>
</div>
```

И отступы, которые вы у вас на рисунке, это не `margin`, а элемент не занимает всю ширину выделенного блока, `CSS`-решение:

```
.panel {
  width: 100%;
}
```

2) Используйте `container-fluid`.

Набросок: [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/eQIROsE/2/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Стало ясно что с этими отступами. 
Хотел бы прояснить чем ваша структура лучше, если можно или почему именно так. 
Еще, если вам не сложно, подскажите пожалуйста как можно отцентровать эти панели по горизонтали, если у них есть фиксированная максимальная ширина (по той причине что, в случае если ширина больше - они смотря просто ужасно, по-этому вариант width: 100% не проходит).

Comment: @AlexanderSigida Моя структура ничем не лучше, просто это пример реализации `container-fluid`. Чтобы не растягивать весь элемент по блоку и сохранить размеры примените: `.panel { display: block; margin: 0 auto;}`. Если помог нажмите стрелку вверх, спасибо.

Comment: Да, помогло, благодарю. Стрелку нажму как будет достаточно репутации)